# Upscaled canvas is not getting antialiased

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, canvas, viewport

I am creating a game where html5 canvas is taking up the entire screen.
But when I use the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

tag, the canvas gets pixelated badly on the newest Chrome for Android.

I have created a simple test (available [here](http://ciebiada.com/test)):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                    radius = 0;

                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

                radius = (canvas.width < canvas.height) ? canvas.width / 3 : canvas.height / 3;

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.fill();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It draws a red dot in the middle of the screen. This works great everywhere except the Chrome for Android. Which renders [this](http://ciebiada.com/test/android.png).

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is due to a change in Chrome for Android where Antialiasing was switched off.

This bug outlines the problem: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=285066

It seems to be back to it's original state in Chrome Beta.